# ticTacToe deny value when it already has a value

Tags: java

I'm currently working on my first program. When I insert a value that already has value inserted by myself, it denies, which is what I want. This doesn't work the same for the pc. How can I make this work.

Below is my Main

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        TicTacToe tTT = new TicTacToe();
        boolean run = true;
        int input = 0;
        String playerInput = "?";

        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        playerInput = scan.nextLine();
        tTT.getPlayerName(playerInput);
        while (tTT.checkRowsForWins()) {
            System.out.println(playerInput + " Insert your value");

            input = tTT.getInput();
            if (input > 9 || input < 0) {
                System.out.println("Wrong value inserted");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You inserted " + input);
//              tTT.insertCross(input);
                tTT.checkRowsForInsert(input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my TicTacToe class, the problem occurs in the method below `public void checkRowsForInsert(int input)`:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {

    private String[] str = new String[9];

    private Random ran;
    private Scanner scan;

    public TicTacToe() {
        ran = new Random();
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void printHex() {
        System.out.println(str[0] + "|" + str[1] + "|" + str[2]);

        System.out.println(str[3] + "+" + str[4] + "+" + str[5]);
        System.out.println(str[6] + "|" + str[7] + "|" + str[8]);
    }

    public int getInput() {
        int i = scan.nextInt();

        return i;
    }

    public void insertCross(int input) {
        str[input] = "X";
    }

    public void insertCrossForCPU() {
        int inputForCPU = ran.nextInt(8);

        str[inputForCPU] = "O";
    }

    public void checkRowsForInsert(int input) {
            if(str[input] != null) {
                System.out.println("Can't insert " + input + " because it already contains a cross or circle");
            } else {
                insertCross(input);
                
                insertCrossForCPU();
                return;
            }
    }

    public boolean checkRowsForWins() {
        boolean result = true;

        if ((str[0] == "X" && str[1] == "X" && str[2] == "X") || 
                (str[3] == "X" && str[4] == "X" && str[5] == "X")|| 
                (str[6] == "X" && str[7] == "X" && str[8] == "X")) {
            result = false;
            System.out.println("You win");
        } else if ((str[0] == "O" && str[1] == "O" && str[2] == "O")
                || (str[3] == "O" && str[4] == "O" && str[5] == "O")
                || (str[6] == "O" && str[7] == "O" && str[8] == "O")) {
            result = false;
            System.out.println("The CPU won....");
        }

        if ((str[0] == "X" && str[4] == "X" && str[8] == "X") 
        ^ (str[2] == "X" && str[4] == "X" && str[6] == "X")) {
            result = false;
            System.out.println("You win");
        } else if ((str[0] == "O" && str[4] == "O" && str[8] == "O")
                ^ (str[2] == "O" && str[4] == "O" && str[6] == "O")) {
            result = false;
            System.out.println("The CPU won....");
        }

        printHex();
        System.out.println();
        return result;
    }

    public String getPlayerName(String input) {
        String name;

        name = input;
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if it solves the problem, but I think it should be

```
if (input > 8 || input < 0)
```

Because your input array "str" goes only from 0 to 8 (which is 9 elements).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is in `public void insertCrossForCPU()` method.

At first `Random.nextInt(int bound)` excludes the bound so you should change it from 8 to 9
and aslo you should do a check to see if the computer is randomly selected the same area as the user or a previous one.

```
public void insertCrossForCPU() {

    boolean flag = false;

    while (flag == false) {
        int inputForCPU = ran.nextInt(9);

        if (str[inputForCPU] == null) {
            str[inputForCPU] = "O";
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Also change

```
if (input > 9 || input < 0) {
     System.out.println("Wrong value inserted");
}
```

To

```
if (input > 8 || input < 0) {
     System.out.println("Wrong value inserted");
}
```

Else you will get an `ArrayOutOfBoundException`